# Why are the 2 Magic Mocks instances different in ID?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to use patch() to inject mock into a call after reading this tutorial: https://kimsereylam.com/python/2021/03/19/how-to-use-patch-in-python-unittest.html, but the expect mock ID is different than actual.

Here is snippet of code to illustrate:

***my_class.py***

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 5
```

***run.py***

```
from my_class import MyClass

def call_first():
    o = MyClass()
    print(o)
    call_second(o)
    
def call_second(myclass):
    print("second is called")
    print(myclass)
```

***main.py***

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_class import MyClass
from run import call_first, call_second

with patch("run.MyClass") as myclass_mock:
    print(myclass_mock)
    print(call_first())
with patch("run.call_second") as call_second_mock:
    call_second_mock.assert_called_once_with(myclass_mock)
```

The output is:

```
<MagicMock name='MyClass' id='140711608367712'>
<MagicMock name='MyClass()' id='140711598743312'>
second is called
<MagicMock name='MyClass()' id='140711598743312'>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    call_second_mock.assert_called_once_with(myclass_mock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 924, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'call_second' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

What did I miss? I am trying to use patch() so I can mock the MyClass() object that is instantiated inside call_first() and passed to call_second().

Comment: Why are you trying to assert that `get_value` was called with a specific argument? It wasn't called with *any* arguments. Plus, it's not a mock, so it doesn't even *have* an `assert_called_once_with` method.

Comment: mb, I added the missing pieces

Comment: You're patching a thing *after* the original thing was called, and then asserting that the mock was called? The mock wasn't called. The original thing was.

Comment: The patch() was called first, then call_first(), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
with patch("run.MyClass") as myclass_mock:
    with patch("run.call_second") as call_second_mock:
        #print(myclass_mock)
        instance = myclass_mock.return_value
        print(instance)
        print(call_first())
        call_second_mock.assert_called_once_with(instance)
```

1. I need to use .return_value to get the MagicMock for the class instance
2. I should mock the `call_second` first